# Comment module: allowing anonymous users to reply to comments

Tags: drupal

I have the permissions set to allow anon users to comment and that works just fine. What I also want is the anon user to have access to the "reply" link for existing comments.

Any idea on how to accomplish it?

I've tried to debug/trace this with no luck. I do know that the comment module's `comment_link()` returns an array containing the comment_reply permission, but I'm relatively new to Drupal and I don't understand what happens to the `$links` array between `comment_link()` and the page rendering.

For what it's worth, if I cut and paste the value of `$links['comment_reply']['href']` from `comment_link()` (according to devel) into the address bar, I (as anon user) can access the reply form, so I believe it's just a matter of getting the link to render properly on the node page and not a permissions issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you see $links['comment_reply'] coming from comment_link(), then it has to be a module or theme altering and removing that link, or the theme not displaying comment links properly. I would first just try and switch to the Garland theme temporarily to see if it's theme related. Otherwise, you'll have to narrow down to which module is responsible via process of elimination.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I had started down the module elimination road with no luck. I hadn't considered the theme and you hit the nail on the head - it's somewhere in the custom theme. Thanks again.